# Bind a linkedlist to a datagridview

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, linked-list

I'm trying to bind a linkedlist to a datagridview. The method below works for the properties in the class except the array. 
If I declare the array as a new instance the linkedlist is created correctly, but the array is not bound into the datagridview. 
If the array is created as a property (I think the code is correct) causes `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred`  when the linkedlist is created.

Thanks for any help.

```
    public class PayoffNode
                {
                    public int DealNo { get; set; }
                    public string Category { get; set; }
                    public string Strategy { get; set; }
                    public string GreekType { get; set; }
                    // declare array as instance or as a property?
                    //public double[] Data = new double[22];  
                    public double[] Data
                    {
                        get { return Data; }
                        set { Data = value; }
                    }
                }

    LinkedList<Globals.PayoffNode> PayLL = new LinkedList<Globals.PayoffNode>();
                Random Rnd = new Random();
                for (int K = 1; K <= 10; K++)
                {
                    var T = new Globals.PayoffNode();
                    T.Category = "Account==" + K;
                    T.GreekType = "Greek==" + K;
                    T.DealNo = K;
                    T.Strategy = "Strategy==" + K;
                    for (int DP = 1; DP <= 21; DP++)
                    {
                        T.Data[DP] = Rnd.Next(10, 99);
                    }
                    PayLL.AddLast(T);
                }

                List<Globals.PayoffNode> qP = (from P in PayLL
                                               where P.Category == "Account==4" && P.DealNo == 4 && P.GreekType == "Greek==4" && P.Strategy == "Strategy==4"
                                               select P).ToList();

     PayoffTable.DataSource = qP;
```

**Update**:
Thanks for the comments, this seems to be working.

```
public class PayoffNode
            {
                public int DealNo { get; set; }
                public string Category { get; set; }
                public string Strategy { get; set; }
                public string GreekType { get; set; }
                public double Data1 { get; set; }
                public double Data2 { get; set; }
                public double Data3 { get; set; }
                public double[] Data = new double[22];
            }

LinkedList<Globals.PayoffNode> PayLL = new LinkedList<Globals.PayoffNode>();
            Random Rnd = new Random();
            for (int K = 1; K <= 10; K++)
            {
                var T = new Globals.PayoffNode();
                T.Category = "Account==" + K;
                T.GreekType = "Greek==" + K;
                T.DealNo = K;
                T.Strategy = "Strategy==" + K;
                for (int DP = 1; DP <= 21; DP++)
                {
                    T.Data[DP] = Rnd.Next(10, 99);
                }
                PayLL.AddLast(T);
            }

List<Globals.PayoffNode> qP = (from P in PayLL
                                           where P.Category == "Account==4" && P.DealNo == 4 && P.GreekType == "Greek==4" && P.Strategy == "Strategy==4"
                                           select new Globals.PayoffNode()
                                           {
                                               Category=P.Category,
                                               DealNo=P.DealNo,
                                               GreekType=P.GreekType,
                                               Strategy=P.Strategy,
                                               Data1=P.Data[1],
                                               Data2 = P.Data[2],
                                               Data3 = P.Data[3],
                                           }).ToList();

PayoffTable.DataSource = qP;
```

Comment: `return Data;` this is causing infinite recursion.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you bind array to a datagridview column?

Comment: I'm hoping to see each record in the datagridview to look like: ``Category-GreekType-DealNo-Strategy-Data[1]-Data[2]...`` So all the variables and then the array

Comment: I wish it was that simple, but unfortunately each public property is bound only to one column, so you will need a separate Data1, Data2, etc property for each column.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was expecting too much from the query. Please take a look at my update and see if you can make it a bit more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid making 21 Data properties is to convert the List to DataTable:

```
class PayoffNode
{
    public int DealNo;
    public string Category;
    public double[] Data; // = new double[21];
}
```

and then

```
Random Rnd = new Random();

List<PayoffNode> PayLL = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new PayoffNode {
    DealNo = i,
    Category = "Account==" + i,
    Data = Enumerable.Range(1, 21).Select(d => (double)Rnd.Next(10, 99)).ToArray()
}).ToList();

// List<PayoffNode> to DataTable
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("DealNo", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Category"); // typeof(string) by default
for (int i = 1; i <= 21; i++)
    dt.Columns.Add("Data" + i, typeof(double));

foreach (var P in PayLL)
{
    var dr = dt.Rows.Add(P.DealNo, P.Category);
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
        dr[i+2] = P.Data[i]; // +2 is the number of fields before the Data fields
}

PayoffTable.DataSource = dt;
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = " Category = 'Account==4' ";
```

The advantage is that you set the `DataSource` only once and just change the `RowFilter` to filter it. Also, any changes made in the `DataGridView` change the `DataTable` and vice-versa.

Note that arrays in C# and most other languages start from 0 and not from 1 ( `.Data[0]` to access the first item in the array ), so the for loop to access the Data array in my example is from 0 to 20.

Comment: Thanks, this looks way more efficient. I just prefer using base 1 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
public double[] Data
{
    get { return Data; }
    set { Data = value; }
}
```

This is the problem, the object in the set and get method needs to refer to a different object otherwise whenever the object value is set or trying to be retrieved it will just keep calling these methods infinitely. should be...

```
private double[] _data;
public double[] Data
{
    get { return _data; }
    set { _data = value; }
}
```

or...

```
public double[] Data { get; set; }
```

Comment: I agree, but your answer doesn't work. I get an error on the line ``T.Data[DP] = Rnd.Next(10, 99);`` saying ``Object reference not set to an instance of an object.``